# Not getting full text from the div tag.BeautifulSoup.Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im  trying to extract text from the div tag.`

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='url'
page = requests.get(url,'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
print(soup.find('div',{'class':'meta-

item salary'}).text)
```

The HTML code:

```
  <div class="meta-item salary">
        <span
            class="icon icon-pound-currency-3"></span> $1000 - $2000 per annum + + excellent benefits    </div>
```

In result I have:
 "excellent package" only no numerical values. Im clueless.

Comment: How do you get "excellent package" as a result? The example HTML doesn't even contain that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
soup.select_one('.icon-pound-currency-3').text
```

Or the following, using a single class from the compound

```
html  = '''

<div class="meta-item salary">
        <span
            class="icon icon-pound-currency-3"></span> $1000 - $2000 per annum + + excellent benefits    </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('div',{'class':'salary'}).text)
```

If there can be more than one match then you need findAll or soup.select and iterate the returned lists. Positional matching is probably possible but would need to see page html.

Comment: it works for your html provided. I am guessing you have more than one class that matches in your actual html? In which case you need to use soup.select or findAll and iterate the returned lists. Or possibly positional match but can't say without seeing page html. The other possibility is the actual page populates values with javascript.

Comment: Page has only one div tag of this class name. Defiantly not generated by JavaScript. What I find strange is that I get only the part of the text inside the tag. Never seen this before..

Comment: Can't say _from a distance_. My code works on your html provided. Can you provide the url?

Comment: Do apologize .I made a mistake of referring to wrong page when coding.... Thanks for anyway. need a brake...